# Deleting a large number of files from MongoDb GridFS

Tags: c#, mongodb

We want to create a batch job that will delete old GridFS files (by either their id or last_update field).

We're currently using the Mongo C# driver:

```
myFS.Delete(Query.And(Query.GT("uploadDate", BsonDateTime.Create(beginDate))
```

While this works, it's VERY slow (over 5 minutes to delete 5k files and their chunks).

Is there a better way to delete a large number of files (and their chunks) from Mongo's GridFS?

Comment: How large are the files you're deleting?

Comment: About half consist of only one chunk

Comment: is the `uploadDate` field indexed?

Comment: The uploadDate field was just an example, we get the same performance when querying against the file name

Comment: Maybe profiler would help: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/